# Angular: How to debug why control is not redirecting to a new route

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm redirecting to a new route after logging-in via this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/firstPage']);
```

When my application is loaded for the first time, this redirection doesn't happen automatically after login. But if the user logs out and logins, then this redirection happens.

**My question is: How to debug why it's not getting redirected, despite this line getting executed? **

I mean, how to debug the issue when no error is being shown and control is passing over this line (as confirmed via debugger)?

Comment: What is the default route you have set for the application?

Comment: Try putting `consoles` before your router and see if the code reaches that level at reload

Comment: @AhmadHabib The code is reaching that line. I saw it in debugger by placing breakpoints

Comment: @VimalPatel The default route is *firstPage* only

Comment: Are you facing this issue on login route, so when user is logged-in and if navigate to login  route then he/she should automatically redirected to FirstPage, correct?

Comment: Do you have any guards set for your routes? If any, then check whether those can prevent the navigation from happening.

Comment: The fact that you say you want to route to a page right after loading the app makes me wonder why you're not using a default route instead. Theres no need to use the router on startup unless you do some kind of auto-redirect.

Comment: I utilise a similar method and I divert then after being authenticated with my STS in my signin-redirect-callback. Do you have some logic to establish if the user is logged in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not able to comment yet so I will post it as answer.

You could try to enable `enableTracing` in router module which will log all navigation events to console.

```
imports: [
RouterModule.forRoot(
  routes,
  { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
)]
```

At first they might seem to be a bit overwhelming but they can be useful in your case since you will be able to see that for example some guard stopped navigation

Comment: It was a guard that was causing this issue silently. I didn't get any information about the guard failing by enabling the tracing though... the redirection simply stopped.

Comment: The tracing is not very useful at all. It tells what happens but not why which is very annoying when you get a fall-through redirect with no information. A half decent piece of code would communicate instances where a change in route occurs.